# find and split command but result to a different directory?

Tags: linux, shell, split

I can not get this work:

```
find /var/lib/vz/dump -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +25G -exec split --bytes=30G /splittedfiles/  {} {} \;
```

Without /splittedfiles/ it runs fine. But I want to put splitted files in a different folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix has to go after the name of the file to be split.  That means you'd need to use:

```
find /var/lib/vz/dump -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +25G \
     -exec split --bytes=30G {} /path/to/split/files/ \;
```

The `{}` is the name of the file to split.  The path to the split files as written would create names like `aa` in the nominated directory.
The main snag would be that the second split file would overwrite the first file's split data.  That's a problem, not easily solved on the `find` command line.  If I were going to do it, I'd arrange to use:

```
… -exec split-script.sh {} +
```

and the `split-script.sh` would deal with the location and tricks like using the base name of the file after `/path/to/split/files/`.  This sort of shell script doesn't have to last for long — you can remove it once you've run this job.

```
for file in "$@"
do
    split -b 30G "$file" "/path/to/split/files/$(basename "$file")."
done
```

(The `.` at the end separates the base name from the `aa` etc suffixes.)